# Passing Variable to Asynchronous JavaScript Function Invoked in Loop (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, this, react-props

I'm writing some JavaScript code for my React project. The code loads a series of images, then updates the state with the dimensions of each image. The problem is that when I invoke the `onload` function, the `this` keyword refers to the object attached to the `onload`. This means I can no longer access props through `this.props`. Is there a way to pass the props into the function?

Here's my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {

  var path = i + ".jpg";
  imgArray[i].index = i;

  imgArray[i].onload = function() {
    this.props.actions.updateImage(this.index, this.width, this.height);
  }

  imgArray[i].src = path;
}
```

I currently get an error, as `this.props` is undefined, since `this` refers to imgArray[i] in the function, not the global context.

Comment: People often save a reference to "this" in another variable, such as "that" or "_this", i.e. `var that = this`. Then you can use that "that" variable in your onload function. You can also use an arrow function if you're using ES6+, since they preserve the binding of "this" to the context in which the function is created. You could also do `.onload = function(){...}.bind(this)` to manually set the this variable in your onload function. If you did either of the last 2 options, you'll need to change how you grab "this.width" and height (hint: check the arguments variable).

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. Super simple too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution might just be to save the context or props into a variable and use them:

```
const { props } = this;

// ...

imgArray[i].onload = function() {
  props.actions.updateImage(this.index, this.width, this.height);
}
```

You can also save the other context if you find that more readable:

```
const ctx = this;

// ...

imgArray[i].onload = function() {
  ctx.props.actions.updateImage(this.index, this.width, this.height);
}
```

Comment: This was my first thought as well, but it might break the references to `this.width` and `this.height`, which I think are meant to reference the image itself, and not the original `this`.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.

Comment: @BobDole glad to help mate

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to capture the props by using a variable that holds a reference to the outer 'this' that you access via the closure:

```
// This line here, now inside the function, use 'self' to refer to outer context
let self = this;
for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {

  var path = i + ".jpg";
  imgArray[i].index = i;

  imgArray[i].onload = function() {
    // note call to self.props instead of this.props:
    self.props.actions.updateImage(this.index, this.width, this.height);
  }

  imgArray[i].src = path;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately these didn't work. I tried the first one, and I got the error "cannot read property 'index' of undefined." So imgArray[i] is undefined for some reason. With the second one, I get the same error (cannot read property 'index' of undefined). It seems like the 'this' keyword is undefined in the second one. Not sure what to do :/

Comment: Yeah, I may have written the answer a bit hastily. Turns out neither of my proposed options were very good, and your best bet is almost certainly to pass your `this` into the function by assigning it to a variable outside the loop, then accessing that instead (much like nem035's answer). I've edited the post.

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't sure which answer to mark as correct but this one is correct too :D

Comment: Definitely the other answer as you did already. He beat me to it so deserves the accept.